# Shift key has unexpected behavior in the terminal

Tags: terminal, vim, shift

I'm running macOS Mojave, and I'm getting strange behavior from my <kbd>Shift</kbd> key.

After I've typed in any text in the terminal, if I press and release the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key, it will add `;2D;10D` to the end of that string. For example, if I type `hello` and immediately press and release <kbd>Shift</kbd> after, it will become `hello;2D;10D`, and it will add that additional string as many times as I press and release <kbd>Shift</kbd>, e.g. pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> twice at the end of `hello` would create `hello;2D;10D;2D;10D`, etc. If I have not typed in any text yet and press and release <kbd>Shift</kbd> nothing happens.

When I am in Vim Insert Mode, or in colon command mode, if I have typed anything, pressing and releasing the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key moves my cursor to right after the first character of that recently created string of characters. For example, I press `i` to enter Insert Mode. `|` represents my cursor. If I type in `hello` and press and release <kbd>Shift</kbd> immediately after, my cursor ends up here `h|ello`. I noticed that in Normal Mode, when I press and release <kbd>Shift</kbd>, the bottom right corner that displays your key press combinations quickly flashes `~@#`.

To debug, I have removed all my plugins and commented out my .vimrc file, and I am still getting the same behavior. This behavior occurs in any terminal emulator I've used (the standard Mac terminal, iTerm2, VSCode command line, etc.) I don't get this behavior outside of the command line, e.g. when I use Microsoft Word, or even typing this now, pressing and releasing the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key has no effect. Any feedback on why this may be occurring would help!

Answer (score 0):

Since it happens on both iTerm and Terminal.app, check the `$TERM` setting and try changing it to another standard terminal. `xterm-256color` usually works well.

```
echo "$TERM"            # remember the output of this so you can return to it if needed!
export TERM='xterm-256color'
```